Animations on char do not work - stays in t-pose
I am separately importing a model and an animation (both FBX; the model is originally in t-pose and the animation is an idle animation) and then remove the armature from the imported animation. Then in Animation -> Action Editor I select the imported animation.
I see that the imported models armature moves, but the movement seems relative to the models t-pose. For example the arms are moving slightly, but instead of hanging down they are stretched to the side.
I used the same procedure on other models and animations and the animations work as expected. When changing the animation in the Action Editor the model immediatelly changes its posture to the first frame of the animation. So I am not sure, why the procedure works with some models/animations and not with others.
I am new to blender and am very likely missing some setting either for the imported model or the imported animation.
Any tips and hints on how to reliably combine imported models and animations would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for any help and best regards,
Patrick

I do recommend you edit in screenshots of what you’re talking about, it’s usually expected as details for the sort of thing. It’s probably why your question got downvoted.

As far as I can tell, this is expected behavior. Animations store bone pose transforms relative to their absolute starting point (where they were placed in edit mode, where they end up if you zero the transforms in pose mode), so if you put an animation on an armature where the absolute starting transform of the bone is different, it will look incorrect. There are, however, addons and tutorials for retargeting animations to new skeletons, as this is a common need for motion capture. I recommend you look into that.
